# Change Windows Store App price

Tags: windows-store

I'd like to submit my app to the windows store. I've done the 'Version 1', which would be filling out the description, uploading the package,...
I've set a price of 1,49$ for my app. If I click on submit and Microsoft tests the app, is it possible to change the price afterwards?

Let's say I've set 1,49$. I click on submit. Microsoft approves the app and it's in the store for 1,49$. Later, I want to change the price to 1,99$... Is it possible to do it just like this?

Answer (score 4):

I just spoke with a Microsoft employee and he told me that it's possible to change the price of the app any time.
All I have to do is to upload a new release and set the new price for the release.
Customers who already bought my app will get the new release and don't have to pay anything extra.

Comment: what if you start out as free and then put a price on the app after few months? will all the users who had downloaded it for free get the new version for free as well?

Comment: @Morpheus Yes, once a user has downloaded your 'free' app, it'll always be free for him/her. But new users will have to pay.